# How to start some instance in Oracle if there are 2 homes path?

Tags: oracle, installation

On Oracle, we have 2 database one is Production and one is Test. Production is lcoated in `dbhome1` and Test is located in `dbhome2`.

We recently had a power outage after which the Production instance (PRDACT) came up automatically, but the Test instance (PRDTST) was not showing when I typed `lsnrctl status`, it showed only `PRDACT`.

Please see the following screenshot:
[image: Listener CTL Status Window]

When I login with username/password for `PRDTST` I received the following error:

```
ORA-12514 TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.
```

Then I checked `tnsname.ora` in the `dbname1` path I found no service name on connected_data for `PRDTST`.

[image: tnsnames.ora for dbname1 path]

After that I checked `tnsnames.ora` in `dbname2` path I found service name is showing normally.

[image: tnsnames.ora for dbname2 path]

How do I start up the Oracle instance `PRDTST`?
Could you please help me for this case?

#### Additional Information After Answer

Thank you for providing us POC for ODA.

However, I used .oraenv to change environment to dbhome2
[image]

But after typed lsnrctl status. PRDTST is still not showing. See result below.

[image]
I'm not sure we need to config for 4 variables or not. Could you please guide on this?

Comment: Utilize . oraenv <<< "SID" (note the dot) to set the different ORACLE_HOME environments. From there you can operate the different databases/listeners.

Comment: Thank you @BjarteBrandt but I'm not sure how can I start PRDTST now. Could yu please advise?

Comment: . oraenv <<< "PRDTST" -> sqlplus / as sysdba -> SQL>startup . Since you have GI installed you can also utilize the tool "srvctl start|status|stop database -d PRDTST"

Comment: Thank you so much @BjarteBrandt. After I ran srvctl start database -d PRDTST , If found error. CRS-2632 there are no more servers to try to place resource. 
Checked trace file and found error below.
2022-11-09 21:29:07.773 :CLSDYNAM:922261248: [ora.prdtst.db]{1:7972:47464} [check] InstConnection::connectInt 020 server not attached
2022-11-09 21:29:07.792 :CLSDYNAM:922261248: [ora.prdtst.db]{1:7972:47464} [check] ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Any suggest on this please?

Comment: You have to set the correct environment before you fire off "srvctl start". Make sure you execute as user "oracle". Make sure environment is correct. "env | grep ORA". Verify environment looking at file "cat /etc/oratab"

Comment: Are you using ODA? It looks like you may be.

Comment: @JohnK.N. Yes I'm using ODA. Anything I need to be careful?

Comment: @BjarteBrandt - Yes I'm using oracle and path point to dbhome2. env | grep ORA is PRDTST , ORACLE_BASE is /u01/app/oracle/ , ORACLE_HOME is /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome2 then I ran srvctl start database -d PRDTST but result is the same. Checked path in cat /etc/oratab path is the same ORACLE_HOME

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Oracle with multiple homes, then you have to change certain variables before you can interact with the corresponding instance. I had the opportunity to work with ODA in a Proof Of Concept and encountered similar issues when trying to interact with certain database instances running in multiple homes, and even more so with PDBs (Pluggable Databases) and CDBs (Multitennant Container Databases). An overview of CDBs and PDBs can be found in the article [CDBs and PDBs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/CDBs-and-PDBs.html#GUID-5C339A60-2163-4ECE-B7A9-4D67D3D894FB) (Oracle | Docs).

When in a Linux environment, you can view the current settings for various ORACLE "variables" by typing `export | grep ORA`. This will provide you with a liste of variables that are valid for the system (and not just in your session).

E.g.

```
...
declare -x ORACLE_BASE="/u00/app/oracle"
declare -x ORACLE_DOC="/u00/app/oracle/product/rdbms19/doc"
declare -x ORACLE_HOME="/u00/app/oracle/product/rdbms19"
declare -x ORACLE_PDB_SID="MYPDB"
declare -x ORACLE_SID="SOMESID"
declare -x ORATAB="/u00/app/oracle/etc/oratab"
declare -x ORA_MODULE=""
...
```

### Switching Oracle Homes

To switch between the different environments, you will have to set the variables for  at least the following Oracle variables by changing them at the bash prompt:

#### Option 1

Manually changing the variables using the bash shell and the `export` command.

```
export ORACLE_SID="PRDTST"
export ORACLE_BASE="/u01/app/oracle/"
export ORACLE_HOME="/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome2"
export TNS_ADMIN="/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome2/network/admin"
```

#### Option 2

Using the `oraenv` utility.

```
# oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [CURRENT_SID] ? <Enter new SID>
```

### Database States

You should be able to view the state of the database in the current scope (after setting all the `ORACLE...` variables) of the current listener by typing the listener commands:

```
lsnrctl status
lsnrctl services
```

### Connecting to SID or CDB

Once you have the service names (e.g. `SERVICE_NAME=SRV_PROD_CDB_01`, you can then connect either directly to the database using the SID if the oracle database is not a non-PDB:

```
# sqlplus sys@PRDTST as sysdba
```

...or if your database is inside a PDB connecting via service:

```
# sqlplus sys@<SERVICE_NAME> as sysdba
```

e.g.

```
# sqlplus sys@SRV_PROD_CDB_01 as sysdba
```

### Checking the Database State

To check the database state with a non-pluggable database instance run:

```
SQL> select dbid, name, open_mode from v$database;
```

With a CDB/PDB execute the following first:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER = CDB$ROOT;
SQL> SHOW PDBS
```

Once you have the PDB name, run (with the name you provided in your question):

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=PRDTST;
SQL> select dbid, name, open_mode from v$database;
```

### Mounting / Opening the Oracle Database or PDB

Once you know the state of your database, run either of the following commands:

#### Database Not Started

```
SQL> STARTUP
```

#### Database Started but not Mounted

```
SQL> ATLER DATABASE OPEN;
```

#### Database Mounted

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

---

***Additional Information after question was redacted***

As mentioned in your comment and edited question, you seem to be having an issue with the Oracle instance not having been registered correctly with the corresponding listener.

#### Check Listener Configuration in Oracle Instance

Log in to your Oracle instance with the following command:

```
# sqlplus sys@PRDTST as sysdba /nolog
```

Once inside the instance query the parameter `local_listener`:

```
SQL> sho parameter local_listener;
```

This should output something similar to the following:

> ```
> NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
> ------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
> local_listener                       string      (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=y
>                                                  ourhost.domain.tld)>     (PORT=152
>                                                  1))
> SQL>
> ```

If the output isn't correct then execute the following command to change the value to correspond with your current listener:

```
SQL> alter system set local_listener='(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=correcthost.domain.tld)(PORT=1521))';
```

<sub>*Change `correcthost.domain.tld` to match your configuration*</sub>

#### Registering Database Instance with Listener

Once you have set the correct value or verified the current value, then execute the following command to add the Oracle instance to your current listener:

```
SQL> alter system register;
```

Once the Oracle instance has been registered with the current listener, execute one of the `lsnrctl` commands to check that the instance is now detected by your current listener.

---

#### Afterword

Because I don't know the exact configuration of your environment I can only provide possible solutions. Your mileage may vary. Sadly I no longer have any output from my ODA POC with which I could have provided more examples. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @John K. N. for your suggestion. However, I used .oraenv to change environment to dbhome2. But after typed lsnrctl status. PRDTST is still not showing. $ORACLE_HOME $ORACLE_SID is already pointed to PRDTST but not showing when type lsnrctl status. Could you please suggest on this?

Comment: @Peung I have added an additional section explaining how an instance can be registered with the listener.

Comment: Thank you for patient with me. I'm quite new to oracle. I changed . oraenv to PRDTST then I typed sqlplus sys@PRDTST as sysdba as you suggested but I got 
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor.
Then I put username only as sys and my password like xxxx as sysdba and I can login. I don't quite understand PDB/CDB quite well. But next step I need to set local listener right as after sho command , output is  no listener I got error ORA-01034: ORACLE not available.

Comment: Try performing the steps I outlined in the **Checking the Database State** section. If that fails, then you possibly have a different issue, which would possibly require a database consultant.